# Radio button needs to be reset while refreshing

Tags: html, drupal

I am having two radio buttons namely users and groups.

If is select groups and refresh the browser it stays in groups itself.

When i give **ctrl+f5** it's getting reset to users.

My need is:

**`While i click the refresh button in browser the radio button should be reset to users even it is selected as groups.`**

**EDIT : CODE**

```
$form['groups'] = array(
          '#title' => t('Groups'),
          '#type' => 'select',
          '#multiple' => 3,
          '#options' => $options,
);

$form['users'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Users'),
    '#description' => t('Separate multiple names with commas.'),
    '#default_value' => '',
);
```

This is task developing using drupal and jquery..

Any help regarding this will be grateful and thankful...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: could you show the markup you're using for your radio buttons?

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="clearItForm.reset();">
<form name="clearItForm">
<input type="radio" name="sweets">Ice Cream<br>
<input type="radio" name="sweets">Candy Bars<br>
<input type="radio" name="sweets">Milk Shakes<br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to Robby Shaw's good answer is to reset the form outside of the html, in some JavaScript.

```
window.onload = function(){
    clearItForm.reset();
}
```